# Netlogo: calculate time using distance traveled and speed

Tags: time, netlogo, agent

I have a model where I want to measure the time it takes for a turtle to travel at a given speed from one point to another, using the scale of the map and speed/fd movement to quantify elapsed real time.

I have speed set to a random number (global variable input on UI) for all ships and a list for each turtle with the coordinates of the path. I use the formula of *time = distance / speed*  but cannot figure out how to count time accurately.

The speed is set to a number around 30, which I would like to use as km/h. The scale of the map is 1000m x 1000m per patch so I have tried using factors of 1000 to fix the calculation to no avail. below is my calculation for time.

```
        to move
          tick
          ask ships with [length current-path != 0] 
              [ 
                let x1 xcor
                let x2 [pxcor] of first current-path 
                let y1 ycor
                let y2 [pycor] of first current-path 
                let distance-traveled sqrt ((x2 - x1)^ 2 + (y2 - y1)^ 2)

                set time ((distance-traveled * meters-per-patch) / (speed) 
                set timelist lput time timelist
                set totaltime sum timelist
                go-to-next-patch-in-current-path 
              ] 
          end
```

This potion calls the movement. I am divding speed/1000 since the number for speed is in the 10's and I want the turtles to move much less than 1 patch each tick to allow it to land directly on the patch coordinates in the list.

```
to go-to-next-patch-in-current-path  

      face first current-path
      ifelse distance first current-path < .1
        [
          move-to first current-path
          set current-path remove-item 0 current-path
        ]
        [
          fd speed / 1000
          set heading towards first current-path
        ]


    end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless. If you want someone to move from x1,y1 to x2,y2. You need to calculate the distance to x2 y2. Suppose you want it to take 4 seconds to move from x1,y1 to x2,y2

For a turtle:

on your setup or when you arrive at x1,y1

```
let t 3
let d distancexy x2 y2
let velocity d / t
facexy x2 y2
```

while you're not at x2,y2

```
fd velocity
```

I think your problem is at every iteration you're recalculating your velocity. You're saying if you're 5 meters away, and want to take 5 seconds, move 1 meter. Then in the next time unit, you'll be 4 meters away and want to take 5 seconds, move .8 meters. etc